# Using OLE in Sql Server Linux Docker container

Tags: sql-server, linux, excel, docker, ole

I have a docker container running Microsoft SQL Server 2017, as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker.

I am trying to import an Excel file into the database as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql:

```
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
     'Excel 12.0; Database=myFile.xlsx', [Data$]);
```

This fails with

```
Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Server 02ae64b55e3f, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.
```

I am pretty sure that this is because Excel or OLE is not installed in the docker container.  Searching google for how to install OLE on linux did not produce any answers that did not involve WINE, which seems likely to be a poor solution.

Is there a good way to install OLE on linux

Comment: If this is a one time import, then can't you do it directly from your system and then get a data dump?

Comment: We may be getting repeated updates in the future, so I would like to automate it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server